# How do I configure a capfile to use curl to communicate to New Relic?

Tags: ruby, curl, capistrano, newrelic

I'm playing around with New Relic and want to alert New Relic to deploys. I can do this on the command line using:

```
curl -H "x-api-key:MY_API_KEY" -d "deployment[application_id]=MY_APP_ID "https://api.newrelic.com/deployments.xml
```

What should should I add to the capfile so capistrano runs the curl above upon deploy?

I know I can install the new relic gem and require it in the Capfile, but wanted to avoid the dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "run" command like this:

```
task :foo, :hosts => "my.example.com" do
  run "curl <your info here>"
end
```

The "run" command string is typical Ruby, so you can use any string delimiters:

```
run %{curl -H "x-api-key:MY_API_KEY" -d ... }
```

And you can embed parameters as usual:

```
key = "xyz"
run %{curl -H "x-api-key:#{key}" -d ... }
```

Good info in the comments from Frederick Chung:

> The "run" command will run it on all the remote hosts. I'd use run_locally or even just ``.

Use "run" if you want to know that each host does deploy; each host will send its own info to New Relic.

Use "run_locally" if you just want to know that your local script has run, and you don't care to know that each remote host deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How would I pass parameters? I tried `run "curl xyz"` before, but couldn't figure out how to pass the parameters.

Comment: Run will run it all on all of the remote hosts - I'd use run_locally or even just ``

Comment: Only one remote host, but that's helpful to know.

Answer (score 1):

They have their own capistrano recipes now: https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/recording-deployments-with-the-ruby-agent